# REST API Endpoint Design: Meta-Data change vs subelement insert

Tags: api, rest, architecture

We are discussing how to build a next evolution of our restful API Design. We have the following problem. Think of a resource that will return playlists that have certain elements. Each playlist has a never changing id. At first this looks pretty straight forward.

```
POST /playlists => create a new playlist, id will be returned
GET /playlists/id => retunrs the playlist contents
POST /playlists/id => insert an element to the playlist
DELETE /playlists/id => delete the whole playlist
```

Next thing we have is that the playlists all have some meta data. E.g. a name. Now how to change that meta data as `POST /playlists/id` is already taken.

Any best practice advice on this?

Comment: are you asking if it is possible to simultaneously use POST /playlists/id and POST /playlists/name ?

Comment: No. Sorry if the question is not that clear. The thing is that we are effectively managing to different things on a playlist endpoint. The subitems and the meta data When querying the endpoint qith GET a combination both should be returned. When posting to it we need to separate ways of updating meta data and adding items.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but you want to PUT (or PATCH) to /playlists/id to update the playlist itself.